# BottomNavigationView stops working after navigating from another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I have 2 items in my BottomNavigationView:

```xml
    <item
        android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_round_home"
        android:title="@fragment_first_title" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_round_confirmation_number"
        android:title="@string/fragment_second_title" />
```

I have setup my BottomNavigationView to work with the NavController:

```kotlin
binding.bottomNavigationBar.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

I also happen to have a `thirdFragment` which is not included in the `BottomNavigationView`. So, the scenario is I first navigate from `firstFragment` to `thirdFragment`. Then from there, I navigate to `secondFragment`:

```kotlin
findNavController().navigate(thirdFragmentDirections.actionThirdFragmentToSecondFragment())
```

Now that I've land on `secondFragment`, selecting `firstFragment` in `BottomNavigationView` won't navigate to it! I know it has something to do with multiple backstacks feature in navigation component, but the more I search about it the more I get confused.

Comment: Add more details on code ( host nav and design navigation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this behavior, we can setup the `BottomNavigationView` in the following way:

```kotlin
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationBar, navController, false)
```